# How to use `%` to jump between single quotes?

Tags: vimscript

As title. I have tried change this option:

```
matchpairs
```

but the result is weird: it will jump to all previous `'` if pressed multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help matchpairs` is this...

```
Only character pairs are allowed that are 
different, thus you cannot jump between two 
double quotes.
```

... in other words, the syntax of matchpairs is "*openchar:closechar*", where *openchar* must not be the same as *closechar*.

these are valid pairs...

```
:set matchpairs=[:]
:set matchpairs={:}
:set matchpairs=(:)
```

but these are invalid, since the open and close characters are the same character...

```
:set matchpairs=':'
:set matchpairs=":"
```

... so, as you can see, matchpairs isn't your solution.

I do not know of a plugin that satisfies your need. Many plugins are smart enough to modify the text between single and double quotes (the surround plugin comes to mind), so you would think adding the ability to use '%' to move back and forth between the open quote and close quote would be quite doable. I don't have the skills to write a solution for you, nor have I found an existing plugin that solves this. Such a plugin may indeed exist, I just haven't found it yet.

I realize this isn't the answer you're looking for. But perhaps it steers you in the right direction.

Comment: It helps :) Really thank you for pointing this out!